# Drop duplicates vs group by with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe `df` and a list of columns `l` which is a list of strings corresponding to the names of some columns of `df`.
I have tried two different things:

```
df.groupby(l,as_index=False)['order_id'].nunique()
```

`order_id` being a column that is not in `l`.
I was quite surprised that the number of rows had dropped significantly by doing so because considering my data set, I should not have many rows that are the same on all columns in `l`.
To check it out, I tried this:

```
df[l].drop_duplicates()
```

And indeed the result of that line has more rows than the result of the first line. However, I cannot understand how the number of rows could be different for those two lines. To me they both should be equal to the number of rows that are different on at least one of the columns in `l`. What am I missing?

Comment: how do you check the number of rows?

Comment: also, do you have any missing values in the columns `l`

Comment: The number of rows is shown when I display the dataframes on Jupyter Notebook. But yeah, I do have missing value, and now that you say it that's probably the issue here. Do you think I could use groupby so that it takes into account the missing values too?

Comment: yep, add the parameter dropna=False in the groupby, so `df.groupby(l,as_index=False, dropna=False)...`

Comment: for clarity, please provide an example of the dataframe .

Comment: Thanks, problem solved with dropna=False!